# Extract OSM snapshots for any point in time from geofabrik osh.pbf files

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, osm-full-history, geofabrik

Has anybody successfully extracted OSM snapshots for any point in time from geofabrik osh.pbf files and convert them to shape files?  I need to extract data from 1 year ago to compare with current data in order to find changes in road network.  I was informed by Geofabrik that it's possible with programs like osmium-tools but I've had a hard time trying to get it installed on a windows machine.  Are there any other tools available for windows with this capability?

Comment: NB: Not sure if the above is a typo. `osm.pbf` files are not suitable for this task. You need to look at `.osh.pbf` (full history extracts) instead.

Comment: @mmd  Thanks, changed to osh but the question is still the same.

Comment: As there seems to be continued demand for a windows version I asked the tool author for an update.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your problem, depending on the size and the required output:

1) Set up a virtual maschine (linux) and use the OSM-History-Splitter (https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-splitter) to clip an [OSM history file](http://planet.osm.org/planet/full-history/) to a BBOX and use the OSM-History-Importer (https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-renderer) to import the clipped file into a PostGIS databse. PostGIS offers a rich set of tools to analyze changes in geometrie and/or tags. The OSM-History-Importer offers some nice visualizations.

2) Use [Overpass-Turbo "augmented-diffs"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Augmented_Diffs). From the wiki-page:

> The augmented diff offers comparison of the result of the same query in two different times. The final result contains all the data of nodes/ways/relations with difference between the starting time and the ending time. (It does not take notice of any intermediate change.)

Your query could look somehow like this: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/pI5

Export your selection as GeoJSON and open it in QGIS. For each feature you'll find the attributes of both timestamps from your comparison and/or the changed geometry of the feature.